# jqPlot does not show ajax data even if ajax returns correct inputs

Tags: jqplot

I am trying to build a simple Ajax based Pie chart but I am getting end of sense what still is wrong. Even if I tried to inspirate by other in this community no success.

My code:

```
            $(document).ready(function(){

                var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot) {
                    var ret = null;
                    console.log(url);
                    console.log(plot);
                    $.ajax({
                        async: false,
                        url: url,
                        dataType:'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            ret = data;
                            console.log(data);
                            console.warn(data);
                            console.log(ret);
                        }
                    });
                    return ret;
                };

                var jsonurl = "sub/auditLogStatusesForGraph_json.dsp";

                plo12 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', jsonurl,{
                    title: 'AJAX JSON Data Renderer',
                    dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
                    seriesDefaults: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                        rendererOptions: {
                            showDataLabels: true
                        }
                    },
                    legend: { show: true, location: 'e' }

                });

            });
```

The jsonurl returns

```
[[['INFO',21451],['ALERT',13201],['ERROR',89],['SYSTEM',30],['0',1]]]
```

But still getting error:

> Error: No data specified  jquery.jqplot.min.js:4:14135

As you can see I have tried to debug the pipeline into console but it seems like the "success" part is not applied at all. Even if I tried to change it to "done".

Any idea what I have wrong there?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code within your   `success: function(data)`

```
plo12 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', jsonurl,{
                    title: 'AJAX JSON Data Renderer',
                    dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
                    seriesDefaults: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                        rendererOptions: {
                            showDataLabels: true
                        }
                    },
                    legend: { show: true, location: 'e' }

                });
```